# Firebase query order

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have multiple posts and each post have it's own comments. I want to query all posts, ordered by their time stamps. I tried:

```
let query = Firebase(url: path)
let query.queryOrderedByChild("commentDate").observeEventType(.ChildAdded)
 { (queryResponse, cancelBlock) { ....
```

"commentDate" are integers on server. At this query I get only the first object

```
let query = Firebase(url: path)
query.queryOrderedByChild("commentDate").queryLimitedToFirst(100).observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (queryResponse, cancelBlock) { ...
```

I get only the first object as well... 
The single solution I have at the moment is to query all :

```
 query.queryOrderedByChild("commentDate").observeEventType(.Value) { (queryResponse, cancelBlock) in ...
```

But using this I must sort the array before showing to user.

Any ideas how can I do to get them sorted on server?

**Edit**
Representation of firebase data:

```
{
  "-KGRZmSIDXz5hHkelthQ" : {
    "something1" : "783151",
    "something2" : "21",
    "something3" : "wjeicisje ejej",
    "comments" : "",
  },
  "-KGRa5skGzA1GAG09Lno" : {
    "something1" : "783151",
    "something2" : "21",
    "something3" : "wjeicisje ejej",
    "comments" : "",
  },
  "-KGVr-tti1zr1M1QLlHL" : {
    "something1" : "783151",
    "something2" : "21",
    "something3" : "wjeicisje ejej",
    "comments" : {
      "-KGX1_rFSBLmQJ7QzCRc" : {
        "commentBody" : "something",
        "commentDate" : 1.461933727259896E9,
        "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
        "commentOwnerName" : "something"
      },
      "-KGX1r5Lnhv9YbQre6as" : {
        "commentBody" : "something",
        "commentDate" : 1.461933797884702E9,
        "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
        "commentOwnerName" : "something"
      },
      "-KGXVGKA0SYm-vRs6zsv" : {
          "commentBody" : "something",
        "commentDate" : 1.461941507496439E9,
        "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
        "commentOwnerName" : "something"
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use value event type instead of child added?

Comment: When i set "Value" i get all the objects. But when i set "child added" i get only one object. To query on server (orderbyChild) i must set observeEventType(.ChildAdded). Here are more infos: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: As far as i know you can do a query with every event type and not just child added. And as stated in the [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types) child added is supposed to only give back 1 object. Have you tried other ordering queries yet? [queryOrderedByChild:, queryOrderedByKey:, queryOrderedByValue, or queryOrderedByPriority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

Comment: i tried them.. ( i dont need priority)

Comment: @AndréKool .ChildAdded returns all of the results one at a time (meaning if there are 10 child nodes, it will return all 10, one at a time) whereas .Value returns all of the results at the same time (all 10 are returned in the snapshot)

Comment: Can you please post your Firebase data structure (as TEXT please, no images). You can obtain that through the Firebase Dashboard, Export button. Once we have that, we can craft up a simple answer for you.

Comment: Here is an ideea about the database strucuture (i cannot show the content): https://instance.firebaseio.com/posts/-KGVr-tti1zr1MASDAL/comments  and here are many objects that have a key for time: https://instance.firebaseio.com/lostPersons/-KGVr-tti1zr1MASDlHL/comments/-KGX1_rFASDASDQJ7QzCRc/commentDate

Comment: @TheStackedOne We don't have access to your firebase so we can't view those links. Can you add the relevant part of your data (or some sample data with the same structure) to your question?

Comment: here you can see a small representation: http://pastebin.com/dG0rX2Xm

Comment: Per the answers, your posts node doesn't have time stamps so ordering them by time stamps would not be possible with the current structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure looks fine, so a simple query will return the results you want

```
let commentsRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("-KGVr-tti1zr1M1QLlHL/comments")

commentsRef.queryOrderedByChild("commentDate").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
  snapshot in

  let nodeData = snapshot.value
  print(nodeData!)

})
```

The above will return each child node, one at a time in the proper order.

If you have a small amount of nodes, you can just read them in at one time and iterate over the snapshot.children like this

```
usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("commentDate").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
  snapshot in

  for child in snapshot.children {
    print(child)
  }

})
```

Both of the above will print out each comment node ordered by commentDate

The above will work only if you are interested in retrieving the comments within each post. If not, you'll need to change your Firebase structure and move the comments to separate node, like this

```
posts
   post_01
   post_02
   etc
```

and a separate comments node that's refers to the post the comment belongs to. Since you want to query for say the comments for post_02, and want them ordered by commentDate, combine the post number and date into a single child.

```
comments
   "-KGX1_rFSBLmQJ7QzCRc" : {
     "for_post_and_commentDate": "post_02_1.461933727259896E9",
     "commentBody" : "something",
     "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
     "commentOwnerName" : "something"
   },
   "-KGX1r5Lnhv9YbQre6as" : {
     "for_post_and_commentDate": "post_02_1.461933797884702E9",
     "commentBody" : "something",
     "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
     "commentOwnerName" : "something"
     },
```

and then modify the query

```
usersRef.queryOrderedByChild("for_post_and_commentDate")
   queryStartingAtValue("post_02_0").queryEndingAtValue("post_02_xxx").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
```

You'll have to figure out your commentDate format as it would be easier to craft starting and ending timestamps if they were stored: 20160430100621 as a yyyymmddhhmmss format, then your timestamps could be queried like this:

```
starting: post_02_0
ending: post_02_99999999999999
```

This also gives you the flexibility to query for comments for post_02 that happened yesterday, or last week.

Comment: Your code will show the comments for a single post in the correct order. But OP asked for "I want to query all posts, ordered by their time stamps". Since a post doesn't have a timestamp, this is not possible.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I made the assumption that since the comments node had the commentDate, that is what they wanted to retrieve. If that is not the case then my answer will not work. I think clarification from the OP is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase can query nested children if you know the entire path (so something like `dimensions/length`). It cannot handle dynamic elements in that path under each child (like your `$commentid/commentDate`).

The only way to get this working is to pull the necessary data up to a level where you can query it. For example, if you keep track of the `lastCommentDate` for each blog post:

```
{
  "-KGRZmSIDXz5hHkelthQ" : {
    "something1" : "783151",
    "something2" : "21",
    "something3" : "wjeicisje ejej",
    "comments" : "",
  },
  "-KGRa5skGzA1GAG09Lno" : {
    "something1" : "783151",
    "something2" : "21",
    "something3" : "wjeicisje ejej",
    "comments" : "",
  },
  "-KGVr-tti1zr1M1QLlHL" : {
    "something1" : "783151",
    "something2" : "21",
    "something3" : "wjeicisje ejej",
    "firstCommentDate": 1.461933727259896E9,
    "lastCommentDate": 1.461941507496439E9,
    "comments" : {
      "-KGX1_rFSBLmQJ7QzCRc" : {
        "commentBody" : "something",
        "commentDate" : 1.461933727259896E9,
        "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
        "commentOwnerName" : "something"
      },
      "-KGX1r5Lnhv9YbQre6as" : {
        "commentBody" : "something",
        "commentDate" : 1.461933797884702E9,
        "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
        "commentOwnerName" : "something"
      },
      "-KGXVGKA0SYm-vRs6zsv" : {
          "commentBody" : "something",
        "commentDate" : 1.461941507496439E9,
        "commentOwnerImageView" : "something",
        "commentOwnerName" : "something"
      },
    },
  }
}
```

With this structure you can query blog posts by their last comment date:

```
ref.orderByChild('lastCommentDate').limitToLast(10).on(...
```

Comment: Hello Frank, to be able to sort like you said above, Does **commentDate(timelapse)** need to be unique regardless timezone? How Can I create unique timestamp? If I use example **yyyyMMddHHmmss** format, and then orderByChild it, I think It can be complicated, It will give incorrect result with limitToLast(10).

Comment: I'd use timestamps, instead of a specific date format. But regardless of that: if two comments were posted in the same second/millesecond, they would both set the `lastCommentDate` to the same value. That will lead to correct behavior.